# Setting global variables through a function

Tags: r, function, environment-variables

Suppose I have four doubles `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` that at various points in my script will assume different real numbers. Assume also that all four doubles have values that center around another double called `X`. Namely, the following relationships must always hold:

- `a = X + 1`
- `b = X + 5`
- `c = X + 10`
- `d = X + 15`

In my script, the value of `X` is always changing. How do I write a function such that `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` change alongside `X`?

Creating the `setAll` function below and calling whenever `X` changes will of course not work but is in the spirit of what I want.:

```
setAll <- function(X) {
    a = X + 1
    b = X + 5
    c = X + 10
    d = X + 15
}
setAll(100) #if X = 100
```

Comment: What about using a custom `environment` for such variables instead of hacking in the `.GlobalEnv`? Or your could also follow some OO guidelines especially with reference classes: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/R5.html

Comment: @daroczig You are welcome to post an answer with an example of either solutions, which indeed sound like superior solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with scripts and you want these global variables in your workspace then use the `<<-` operator: `?"<<-"`  Be careful though - this approach assumes that your critical variables don't get changed by any means other than what you intend, and are not very portable.

Update: Your `setAll` function should work if you change it to `setAll <- function()` - no argument is needed if `X` is reset each time with the `<<-` operator.

Answer (score 5):

If you'd want to keep the clutter at a minimal level in the `.GlovalEnv`, it might be better to keep all these variables in a separate environment, e.g.:

```
> setAll <- function(X) {
+     if (!(exists('myParams') && is.environment(myParams))) {
+         myParams <- new.env()
+     }
+     myParams$a = X + 1
+     myParams$b = X + 5
+     myParams$c = X + 10
+     myParams$d = X + 15
+ }
> setAll(100) #if X = 100
> myParams$a
[1] 101
```

Or you might just create a reference class in the means of OO programming as an alternative solution:

```
> myParam <- setRefClass('myParam', fields = list('X' = 'numeric', 'a' = 'numeric', 'b' = 'numeric', 'c' = 'numeric', 'd' = 'numeric'))
> myParam$methods(initialize = function(X, ...) {
+     .self$a <- X + 1
+     .self$b <- X + 5
+     .self$c <- X + 10
+     .self$d <- X + 15
+     callSuper(...)
+ })
> foo <- myParam(pi)
> foo$a
[1] 4.141593
> foo$b
[1] 8.141593
...
```

Sure, these are just initial and dummy wire-frames, but hopefully this would be useful for further ideas.